# "not-null property references a null or transient value" when deleting an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, fluent-nhibernate, objectdatasource

Using ASP.NET/C#/fluent Hibernate architecture, I am trying to use a `GridView` and `ObjectDataSource` to manage my business objects.  I have a main class `Project` with a one-to-many relationship with `OIC` - simplified mappings and classes below.

```
// OIC class definition
public partial class OIC
{
    public int pkOICID { get; set; }
    public string Guarantor { get; set; }
    // ... other fields
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

// OIC mapping
public class OICMap : ClassMap<OIC>
{
    public OICMap()
    {
        Table(@"OIC");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.pkOICID)            // primary key for OIC
          .Column("pkOICID")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Guarantor)
          .Column("Guarantor")
          .Not.Nullable();
        // ...more fields not listed
        References(x => x.Project)    // foreign key to Project
          .Class<Project>()
          .Access.Property()
          .Cascade.None()
          .LazyLoad()
          .Columns("fkProjectID");
    }
}

// Project class definition
public partial class Project
{
    public int pkProjectID { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Iesi.Collections.ISet OICs { get; set; }
}

// Project mapping
public class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Table(@"Project");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.pkProjectID)
          .Column("pkProjectID")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        // ...
        HasMany<OIC>(x => x.OICs)
          .Access.Property()
          .AsSet()
          .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
          .LazyLoad()
          .Inverse()
          .Not.Generic()
          .KeyColumns.Add("fkProjectID", mapping => mapping.Name("fkProjectID")
                                                               .SqlType("int")
                                                               .Not.Nullable());
    }
}
```

When doing unit testing on my repositories, all of the CRUD operations for the OIC class worked perfectly, so I know that the mappings work.  However, when I use a `GridView` and `ObjectDataSource` to try and delete an instance of OIC, I get a "not-null property references a null or transient value CLS.BusinessLayer.Model.OIC.Guarantor" exception when I try to commit the transaction.

Setting a breakpoint and inspecting the object in the repository's Remove function (code below) reveals that only the primary key for the OIC object is being populated - the rest of the fields are null.

```
public virtual void Remove(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    _session = NHibernateSessionProvider.GetSession();
    if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                _session.Delete(entity);
                transaction.Commit();      // exception caused here
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    else
        _session.Delete(entity);
}
```

If I remove the `.Not.Nullable()` on the Guarantor property in OIC, the delete works fine (I only tried this out of curiosity).  Also, if I include the Guarantor field in the list of `DataKeyNames` for my `GridView`, the field is correctly populated when I inspect the object in the `Remove()` function above, and the transaction commits successfully.  Currently, the `GridView` only contains pkOICID - the primary key, in `DataKeyNames`.

So there are a couple things I am stuck on:

1. If I am only removing an object and have the primary key, why does nHibernate care if other fields are null?
2. More importantly, I figure I must be missing something in the `GridView` or `ObjectDataSource` that is causing the object not to be fully populated before being deleted - is this something that needs to be done in `ObjectDataSource_Deleting()` or elsewhere?

Please let me know if more code or explanation is needed - thank you.

Comment: `entity` is of type `OIC`? Does using `_session.Delete(entity.Id)` work?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I'm using a generic repository to be used for all basic CRUD operations - so in this case yes, `entity` is of type `OIC`.  I made a quick OIC-specific repository, but that gives me a "No persister for: System.Int32" exception on the `_session.Delete(entity.pkOIDID)` call.

Comment: a well detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19502535/1348121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work to delete when only the id is known/populated

```
session.Delete(Session.Get(entity.GetType(), entity.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Firo.  I still wish I knew why nHibernate checked for nulls on delete (might be a bug related to: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2792), but I modified my classes and used an interface to effectively get the ID from each business object.

Comment: My guess is that it was easier to implement in the current architecture and it handles some special cases like pending updates, one-to-many which have to be updated, optimistic concurrency with dirty properties, audit triggers or listeners

Comment: I have implemented like this. but it says entity has not a property named Id:  public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            session.Delete(session.Get(entity.GetType(),entity.Id));
        }

Comment: does your entity have an Id property? Is it spelled differently? Does the Typeargument T allow access to the Id property?